# multiple declaration errors of algebraic data type

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

some algebraic data types..

```
data Cell0=Cell0 {c0str::Text,c0uid::Uid}
           deriving (Data,Typeable,Show)
data Cell1=Cell1 {c1start::Uid,c1end::Uid,c1str::Text,c1uid::Int}
           deriving (Data,Typeable,Show)
data Cell2=Cell2 {c2start::Uid,c2end::Uid,c2str::Text,c2uid::Int}
           deriving (Data,Typeable,Show)
data Acell=Cell0|Cell1
```

but the last line induces a compile error "multiple declarations of Cell0"

I also tried sth like this:

```
data A=Aasdfdsf {sdf::Text}
      deriving (Data,Typeable,Show)
data B=Bsdfsd
data AB=A|B
```

It compiles! so weired..

Comment: `data Cell0 = Cell0 ...` defines a `Cell0` constructor, then `data Acell = Cell0 | Cell1` does so again. Maybe change it to `data Acell = ACell0 Cell0 | ACell1 Cell1`?

Comment: that works but too redundant..

Comment: One option is to use `Either`.

Comment: Do you definitely need separate `Cell0`, `Cell1`, and `Cell2` types? Perhaps you should just have one `Cell` type with three constructors, instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data Acell=Cell0|Cell1
```

That's not how ADTs work.

What you're thinking when you write that seems to be "an Acell is either a Cell0 or a Cell1". But the Haskell spec says that this actually means "introduce a new type Acell, and introduce a new constructor Cell0 that takes no arguments, and introduce a new constructor Cell1 that takes no arguments".

Thus your type definition contains no references at all to the type Cell0, but it introduces a new constructor Cell0 that clashes with the existing constructor named Cell0. Hence the error.

Your second example with `data AB=A|B` does *not* work. It compiles, but if you'd tried it you'd see that you cannot put an element of the type `A` in the type `AB`. An AB is either the constructor A (containing no other data), or the constructor B (containing no other data); totally unrelated to the types A and B.

The problem is that ADTs have *tagged* unions; in every branch of a `data` declaration (separated by `|`) there must be a new constructor and *then* the types that will be stored in the constructor. So, for example, you could say:

```
data Acell = Acell0 Cell0 | Acell1 Cell1
```

The constructors function as "tags" and allow you to tell which "branch" is being used without looking at the data inside, and even if the branches actually store the same data (e.g. `data Foo = L Integer | R Integer`). There's no way to have untagged unions and leave out the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are in fact declaring the constructor `Cell0` twice; once in the first type, and once in the last. You're doing the same for `Cell1` aswell, but the compiler hasn't gotten there to produce an error. It doesn't matter that the constructors are of a different type; all constructors must have unique names (the same goes for record fields; an unfortunate part of Haskell).

In your second example, you never try to redeclare a constructor, so it compiles.

Comment: so how to modify the code in the minimal way to make it work? the most straight forward way might be that: data Cell0=Cell0c {c0str::Text,c0uid::Uid}
           deriving (Data,Typeable,Show)

Comment: If you do that, `data Acell = Cell0 | Cell1` will still not work, because `Cell0` will not refer to the type, it will be interpreted as a constructor. If you don't want that, move the `Cell0` declaration into the `Acell` definition, i.e. `data Acell = Cell0 {c0str...} | Cell1 {c1start...}`

Comment: @doofin I'd give each type a more descriptive name to describe its purpose. For example, what's the difference between the `0` and `1` variants of `Cell`?

Comment: @doofin Also note that if your intent in the last type is to refer to the previously constructors, where `ACell` can either be a type `Cell0` or `Cell1`, it doesn't work like that.